# Can't understand how stuxnet was bogusly signed

Tags: certificates, digital-signature

Wikipedia says that

> Its device drivers have been digitally signed with the private keys of
>   two certificates that were stolen from separate well-known companies,
>   JMicron and Realtek, both located at Hsinchu Science Park in Taiwan

<sup>**Source: [Wikipedia - Stuxnet - Windows infection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stuxnet#Windows_infection)**</sup>

However, I can't understand how stolen certificates make the drivers be digitally signed with the private keys of JMicron and Realtek.
As far as I know, certificate has only information of a company, and its public key. There's no information about private key in certificate. 
Does it mean that their private keys were stolen too?

Comment: Well, most report has a habit of simplify the term and say "stolen certificate", which actually mean `certificate issuance private key` is stolen.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is not the certificates that have been stolen, but their private keys.

The formulation is indeed ambiguous. You should read it this way:

> Its device drivers have been digitally signed with **the private keys** (of two certificates) **that were stolen** from separate well-known companies, JMicron and Realtek, both located at Hsinchu Science Park in Taiwan

(Parentheses and emphases are mines.)

I suppose the term certificate has been added to help the reader understand that they're talking about asymmetric cryptography, certificates, and trusted third parties.